# Angularjs, how to structure my code across multiple files

Tags: angularjs, controller, structure, directive

I'm new to AngularJS and have a question regarding the structure of AngularJS.

[Here is a simple working Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/V2yWoV5eeH7oaGYzXjHW?p=preview) I was working on, which displays the map.

**So my question is:**

how do you separate out `<mapbox callback="callback"></mapbox>` if I want to create a file in the view folder instead of putting it into app.js?

I have tried creating a *show.html* file inside of my view folder and pasted that line of code, but it didn't work.

Should I change `'template': '<mapbox callback="callback"></mapbox>'` to

`templateUrl: 'views/show.html'`?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I slightly modified your plunker to show how can you can do it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fpst5cd6gfIh30eOk447

Basically, what I did there was to create a new html file, name it `mapbox.html` and paste the html template there from app.js. Afterwards, I edited the app.js config block to use the `templateUrl` property  pointing to the new file above and deleted the `template` property one, et voilà!

Comment: thanks a lot! by the way what is root in the $stateProvider.state?

Comment: It's the name of the initial state of your app. [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) is the ui-router documentation.